# Font-size related layout issue

Tags: bug, design

I keep my zoom level set at 90% in Chrome and I noticed that on the main StackOverflow site the search box on the top navigation bar has moved to below my name:

[image]

If I change the zoom level to 100% or even 75% it moves back to the correct location.  I am only able to replicate this in Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 (Windows XP) - which I believe is the current stable version of the browser.

Can this be fixed?

Edit, I just noticed that the featured tab on the main page is also off:

[image]

Edit #2, this behavior is also appearing in the flagging window. The Flag Question button has dropped to below the number of flag left.:

[image]

Comment: What OS? I cannot reproduce this on OS X 10.7.5 (with the same Chrome version).

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry, Windows XP Chrome

Comment: I was able to reproduce this in Windows 7, Chrome.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA glad its not just winXP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a rounding bug in chrome since zoom shouldn't affect layout at all.  There's not much we can do about this besides changing some limits...and when that happens more flags or suggested edit indicators will just cause it again.

This really needs to be fixed on the Chrome side (for Windows users only it appears).