# SO search box goes out of place on Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 m

Tags: bug, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Font-size related layout issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155549/font-size-related-layout-issue)

Since a week or two, on my machine, the following has been happening:

[image: Search box out of place]

As you can see, the search box on SO goes out of place, and then it will seemingly randomly go back in place.

I'm guessing this is not supposed to be, so I'm reporting it as a UI bug.

Comment: Do you use a page scaling? 90% perhaps?

Comment: hmmm yes my zoom scale seemed to be set to 90% indeed. Thanks. Wasn't an SO Bug then

Comment: I didn't say that; but it is most likely a Chrome bug since it only applies to Windows users so far.

Answer (score 0):

Using browser zooming can confuse the layout of the web site.

To reset you browser zoom, at least in chrome, press ctrl+0